# Google Analytics - bad experiences? (esp. adult content)

Tags: google, analytics

I work for a rather large adult website, and we're currently not using Google Analytics. There is an internal debate going on about whether we should start using Analytics, but there is hestitation from certain parties. The main argument is that they fear that Google will get too much insight into our website, and might even block us from the index as a result based on our adult content.

Has anyone here ever had such an experience, or know stories about bad experiences with Google Analytics in such a manner? I personally think it will only improve our website if we were able to use Analytics, but the dev team was asked to look into possible negative effects. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any more people with experience with this? Some no's would be ok as well :)

Comment: There are other alternatives out there if the content of your site is of an adult nature. Have you considered Piwik - www.piwik.com ?

Comment: We did, back then, but in the meantime I've been able to convince my colleagues to use GA and they're loving it. Thanks for the late reply anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use it.  I have done work for some major adult sites, and they all use GA.  They are not going to block you or anything like that.  If Google is indexing your site (on any level) they already know your content.  Google just treats any adult content site differently than non adult content. Google already blocks all adult sites from autocomplete, so no worry there on that point.  If you take a look at RealityKings and BangBros for example, they use GA.  And you cant get any bigger and better than those two sites, so they have to be doing it right.  If your dev team can come up with specific examples of what they are worried about, we might be able to give them a more detailed answer.  Most adult sites in my experience, have crappy seo and coding in general, except the bigger brand names.  And even so, some of the big ones still suck in the code/seo department.  I really think you can only benefit from GA.  It's going to help you pinpoint your good and bad pages, so you can improve specific pages or see that a certain page is doing well, seo wise.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! I already know all the benefits of using Analytics, but glad to hear from someone with experience in the same sector. I'll take a look at other sites that use GA to add up to the evidence that GA + porn is not necessarily a bad idea.

Comment: No problem.  If you don't know about it already, Wappalyzer is a great addon to Firefox to determine what softwares a site is using automatically (like GA).  Right when you visit a site, it will show you all what it is using.  Great for saving time. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/wappalyzer.  And if your dev team does have specific worries, please post back, as I would like to know what they are concerned about.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the plugin. I'll let you know when I know more specifics that I have questions about :)